# how to make a string word wise(so that later i can reverse them ) store in  array?? in C

Tags: c, string

my code goes like this !!

```
int i=0,j=0,k=0;
 char *a[20];
 int count=0;
 for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
       a[i] = malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
    }
   i=0; 
 while(*(p+i)!='\n')
 {
  int k=0; 
   while(*(p+i)!=' ')
     {
    *(a[j]+k)=*(p+i);
    i++;
    k++;
   }
   *(a[j]+k)='\0';
                 i++;
          j++;
 }
 printf("\n Count%d",j);
 count=j;
 for(j=0;j<count;j++)
 {
  printf("%s",a[j]);
    printf("\n \n ");
  }
}
```

Comment: Were you specifically forbidden from using `strtok()`?

Comment: Store a string in an array?Isnt breaking the string into multiple strings of words was a better thing to write?

Comment: your code above, besides being pretty much unreadable, never defines `p`.   Additionally, `sizeof(char)` is not necessary.

Comment: @John: There are architectures where actually "sizeof(char) != 1".

Comment: @onemasse: C99 defines implicit, that sizeof(char)==1, see 6.5.3.4. CHAR_BIT must not be 8, but that is an other question

Answer (score 2):

'Better' than strtok & Co see below:

```
int strsplit(const char *s,char ***l,char t)
{
  int r=0;
  while( strchr(s,t) )
  {
    *l=realloc(*l,++r*sizeof*l);
    memcpy((*l)[r-1]=calloc(1,strchr(s,t)-s+1),s,strchr(s,t)-s);
    s=strchr(s,t)+1;
  }
  *l=realloc(*l,++r*sizeof*l);
  memcpy((*l)[r-1]=calloc(1,strlen(s)+1),s,strlen(s));
  return r;
}

int main()
{
    char **l=0,*x="1;2;;4";
    int i,r=strsplit(x,&l,';');
    for(i=0;i<r;++i)
    {
      puts(l[i]);
      free(l[i]);
    }
    free(l);
    return 0;
}
```

better because the string can be const, it work in multithreads, empty works are not be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say whether or not your code actually works. Is there a problem or are you just asking for comments on your code? Your code will fail if there is any word longer than 49 characters.

You might instead use the library function strtok() to  break up a string into tokens/words.

Comment: strtok destroys the string, strtok works not in multi-threads, strtok switch over empty words, like "1;2;;4" -> "1","2","4" and NOT "1","2","","4"